# Spring Boot 2.2.6 No context given for SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy at Logback

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

When I use these configuration:

```
logging:
  file:
    name: app.log
    total-size-cap: 50MB
    max-size: 2MB
    max-history: 7
    path: logs
```

I get this information at application startup:

```
LOGBACK: No context given for c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@1818544933
```

When I create a dummy `logback-spring.xml` file there are no errors but application properties are ignored:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
</configuration>
```

What I am missing at the configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a legitimate issue. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/21056 has a bugfix targeted to the next 2.2.x release. Sounds like adding logback-spring.xml to y

Answer (score 0):

Firsyly, you can not use both 'name' and 'path'. It's either of them.
Secondly, you need to set logging.config=/path/to/logback.xml

Here is my source of information: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-logging-file-output